# -[SFOAuthCoordinator setAuthInfo:]: message sent to deallocated instance crash

Tags: ios, salesforce

I'm receiving this crash in my iOS app using Salesforce after user taps on 'Deny' button in app permission screen after login. 
I have referred sample app given by SF for & it’s displaying an error alert for same scenario.
Don’t know what I’m missing

**Error:**
*Error Domain=com.salesforce.OAuth.ErrorDomain Code=669 "end-user denied authorization" UserInfo=0x1d8ab880 {NSLocalizedDescription=end-user denied authorization, error=access_denied}*

*-[SFOAuthCoordinator setAuthInfo:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x189b1370*

Below is the code I’m using:

**Appdelegate:**

*init method*

```
[SFLogger setLogLevel:SFLogLevelDebug];
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].connectedAppId = RemoteAccessConsumerKey;
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].connectedAppCallbackUri = OAuthRedirectURI;
    [SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].authScopes = @[ @"web", @"api" ];

__weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;

[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].postLaunchAction = ^(SFSDKLaunchAction launchActionList) {
    [weakSelf setupRootViewController];
};
[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].launchErrorAction = ^(NSError *error, SFSDKLaunchAction launchActionList) {
     [weakSelf initializeAppViewState];
    [[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager] launch];
};
[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].postLogoutAction = ^{
    [weakSelf handleSdkManagerLogout];
};
[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager].switchUserAction = ^(SFUserAccount *fromUser, SFUserAccount *toUser) {
    [weakSelf handleUserSwitch:fromUser toUser:toUser];
```

*didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*

```
 [[SalesforceSDKManager sharedManager] launch];
```

**ViewController: (deferred login)**

```
 [[SFAuthenticationManager sharedManager] loginWithCompletion:^(SFOAuthInfo *sfOAuthInfo) {
        NSLog(@"authentication successful!!!");
    }
    failure:^(SFOAuthInfo *sfOAuthInfo, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Authentication failure!!!");
    }];
```

Comment: Did you ever try to use NSZombieEnabled option?